# Kafka Configuration [TOPIC] to collect system logs using ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, filebeat, elk

Kafka configuration to collect system logs

I trying to collect system logs using Elasticstack + Kibana. I have setup system in below format:

> Filebeat -> Kafka -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch <- Kibana.

My system is ready, but not able to collect logs. I am facing issue to set up the Kafka configuration part under filebeat output section.

Please let me know how to collect system logs using filebeat and Kafka.

Comment: please look into it https://logz.io/blog/kafka-logging/

Comment: Please, share your filebeat and logstash configuration so people can see what you are trying to do and what is your error.